# email can't read base64's = token at last

Tags: email, gmail

ok i don't know if it is a simple or tough question but i have no clue to resolve it

what i am doing is converting an email-id:currenttime:date:mobile to base64 and sending that token to that email (token is used for forgetting password).

now in email(gmail) say it is showing like this

abc.com/restyourpass/bGFrc2htaS5kZXZpQGdlbmllZG9jLmNvbToxNDY5NTkzODMwNTA0OjgzNzM5MDAzMTY=

when user click on the link sent to the email, gmail or any other email provider 
reads this url ->
abc.com/restyourpass/bGFrc2htaS5kZXZpQGdlbmllZG9jLmNvbToxNDY5NTkzODMwNTA0OjgzNzM5MDAzMTY (except "=" at the last)

now in gmail or any other email provider they are not able to read "=" at the last of the token, how can i solve this situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "cant able to read" ?  Presumably your users would be clicking this link to do something like activate an account, reset a password, etc.  Does the full link show in the email, and can the user click on that link successfully?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen provider is not able to read the = in the url link